Configurable attribute "deps" in @XNNPACK//:prod_microkernels doesn't match this configuration
I am building Tensorflow on s390x platform using command:
bazel build --define=tensorflow_mkldnn_contraction_kernel=0 --define tflite_with_xnnpack=false //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:wheel --repo_env=WHEEL_NAME=tensorflow_cpu
Build fails with an error:
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/efb88f6336d9c4a18216fb94287b8d97/external/XNNPACK/BUILD.bazel:2998:26: configurable attribute "deps" in @XNNPACK//:prod_microkernels doesn't match this configuration. Would a default condition help?

Conditions checked:
 @XNNPACK//build_config:aarch32
 @XNNPACK//build_config:aarch64
 @XNNPACK//build_config:x86
 @XNNPACK//build_config:emscripten_wasm
 @XNNPACK//build_config:emscripten_wasmsimd
 @XNNPACK//build_config:emscripten_wasmrelaxedsimd
 @XNNPACK//build_config:riscv

Tried to check the code which populates build_config however didn't get much information.

Hi @Nayana,There is a mismatch between the conditions specified in the reps attribute of the @XNNPACK//:prod_microkernels target and the platform you're building for, specifically for the s390x architecture. To resolve this you need to add some custom configuration for s390x in
XNNPACK build files or disable XNNPACK entirely, it is not Crucial for you build,Try it if you are still facing an issue let me know me know,Thanks.
